# Restoring private Nuget package hosted in Azure DevOps with Github Actions fails

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, github-actions, nuget-package

I have a .NET project that uses a private Nuget package that is hosted in Azure DevOps. I have a Github Actions workflow that registers the private feed with a personal access token, and restores the packages in the solution.
This action fails with `error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source`
I have ensured that the feed is enabled, and that the personal access token has read rights on the Azure Artifact.

```
name: tests

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      projectName:
        description: "Project name"
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      PAT:
        required: true
      USER:
        required: true

env:
  DOTNET_VERSION: "7.0.x"

jobs:
  unit-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup dotnet
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
  
      - name: Run tests
        working-directory: ./Solution
        run: |
          dotnet nuget update source private-source-name --source ${{ vars.PACKAGE_URL }} --username ${{ secrets.USER }} --password ${{ secrets.PAT }} --store-password-in-clear-text
          dotnet restore
          dotnet test Solution.Test.${{ inputs.projectName }}
```

I have tried to register the feed and restore as per dotnet documentation, both from solution-level NuGet.Config, as well as top level NuGet.Config, and ensured the config is correctly set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="private-source-name" value="private-source" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <private-source-name>
        <add key="Username" value="<username>" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<clear-text-PAT>" />
      </private-source-name>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

follwed by `dotnet restore` in the Solution. I have also done it with `nuget restore` from the specified config files.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source`, the Nuget.Config could not have correct content. You can add `cat Nuget.Config` command after the `dotnet nuget update source ...` command to check the content, make sure it has correct value replaced, specially for the variable passing.

```
      - name: Run tests
        working-directory: ./Solution
        run: |
          dotnet nuget update source private-source-name --source ${{ vars.PACKAGE_URL }} --username ${{ secrets.USER }} --password ${{ secrets.PAT }} --store-password-in-clear-text
          cat NuGet.Config
          dotnet restore
```

I follow your NuGet.Config, and fix some syntax:

**Before** `dotnet nuget update source` command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="private-source-name" value="private-source" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <private-source-name>
        <add key="Username" value="username" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%PAT%" />
      </private-source-name>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

**After** update command, check in build:
[image]

Confirm the package is restored:

[image]

Edit: update with github action screenshots.

Edit2: As it's failed to restore the package from local machine with command `dotnet restore...`, it's recommended to double check the items below:

1. The user account(which is used to create PAT) has `contributor` or `reader` on the target nuget feed.

[image]

2. Regenerate the PAT, simply try with full scope permission. You can change the permission scope after it works.
   [image]

3.Get the feed url from DevOps artifact, and make sure it's correct in nuget.config. Also make sure other fields(user, PAT...etc) is updated.

[image]

4. Make sure the nuget.config is in the same folder with your project(csproj) file.

Use `dotnet restore -s <feedurl> <csproj file> --verbosity detailed` to check if it works.

Comment: This gives me the same result as previously. I'm actually not able to restore it locally either when not using Rider. Seems like Rider does some magic to successfully restore it, but when I tried to do it fully from VS Code, I get the same results as on the Github Actions runner. I've also made sure that I have Reader on the DevOps project, and that the PAT has package read privilege. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Not familiar with Rider. But your account should have related permission(reader or contributor) on the target DevOps `Feed` (doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#feed-settings)) not just the project, please confirm this. In addition, since you are using `ubuntu-latest` for the github action which should have `no` network restriction to DevOps feed, what need to check is only the source url, pat token, have you checked `cat nuget.config` content?

Comment: I am able to view the feed through a browser by entering the https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/source_name...../index.json so it shouldn't be an access issue. Also, Rider is hooked up to the same account I authenticate with the feed, which works. I have done a `cat` on the `nuget.config` in the Github Action job, and it comes out just like you described it above, but still giving the same error.

Comment: Please narrow the issue with below steps: 1. replace the PAT in the nuget.config file, put it in the same folder with csproj. 2. run the command `dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/project/_packaging/feedname/nuget/v3/index.json" "WebApplication1.csproj" `, will it restore successfully?

Comment: Ok, so I followed your steps by placing the `nuget.config` with credentials inside a project folder and running the `dotnet restore` command you described against the feed, but still get the same `error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source <package-feed>`

Comment: Hi @gormaar, as it's failed directly with local command, it's recommended to double check the settings&permissions needed. I have added the details in the reply, could you please follow the steps for a check?